# Chrome extension getting selected text JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was wondering what is the easiest way to get selected text from tab and put string into a variable

My Popup html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
          <button id="clickme">click me</button>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
          <textarea id="output"> </textarea>
        <script src = "popup.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

My javaScript

```
    chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
  code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function(selection) {
  document.getElementById("output").value = selection[0];
});
```

I tried this but got an error

*

> Error in response to tabs.executeScript: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property '0' of undefined
>       at Object.callback (chrome-extension://nnhcblfafgjjoolcnjckidjgjcmmgnlp/popup.js:4:54)
>       at chrome-extension://nnhcblfafgjjoolcnjckidjgjcmmgnlp/popup.js:1:13

*

Comment: perhaps you need to check if `selection` is not `undefined` before blindly using `selection[0]`

Comment: oh so i need to make a selection array, do you know how to

Comment: no idea, you need to check what selection is before blindly assuming it's what you want it to be - I don't even know if your code is valid, because you've posted so little

Comment: I was more asking if anyone has some simple code that gets selected text in javascript

Comment: fair enough, I was merely pointing out the flaw in your code

Comment: I assume the javascript is in background.js?

Comment: Are you trying to get the content selected on the tab and add it to the textarea on the popup? If yes, you would need messaging passing from popup to frontend and so forth. Let me know and I can provide code.

Comment: The code is correct, just add a check for undefined. Make sure your manifest.json contains correct permissions. And don't try to run the code on built-in chrome:// or chrome-extension:// pages.